# Django - Confirmation page before change of different models

Tags: django, forms, model, confirm, confirmation

I'd like to create a confirmation page for selected objects before a change is made to them (outside the admin). The objects can be of different models (but only one model a time).

This is much like what is done in administration before deletion. But the admin code is complex and I haven't grasped how it is done there.

First I have severall forms that filter the objects differently and then I pass the queryset to the action / confirmation page. I have created a form factory so that I can define different querysets depending on model (as seen in another similiar question here at Stackoverflow):

```
def action_factory(queryset):
    ''' Form factory that returns a form that allows user to change status on commissions (sale, lead or click)
    '''
    class _ActionForm(forms.Form):
        items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = queryset, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
        actions = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('A', 'Approve'), ('D' ,'Deny'), ('W' ,'Under review'), ('C' ,'Closed')))
    return _ActionForm
```

Which I use in my view:

```
context['form']=action_factory(queryset)()
```

The problem is that the items field wont be displayed at all in the html-code when it is hidden. When I remove the HiddenInput widget it displays the form correctly.

I don't want to display the choice field since there can be thousands of objects. All I want to have is something like "Do you want to change the status of 1000 objects" and a popdown and a submit button. A simple enough problem it seems, but I can't get it to work.

If someone has a solution to my current attempt I would be glad to hear how they have done it. Even better would be if there is a cleaner and better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong widget. It should be MultipleHiddenInput not HiddenInput.